# Is there any REST APIs for native kubectl cmds like apply/delete etc

Tags: azure, kubernetes, kubectl

I am trying to write an automation script in for deploying some application to azure kubernetes service. So, I need some REST APIs or client libraries that i can use instead of using kubectl native cmds. I can either use C# or Powershell for automation script.

I have found one client library for managing kubernetes cluster with dotnet but it does not seems to support apply/delete cmds. [Link](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/csharp)

Comment: the link you provided for the csharp library includes delete/create statements right on the first page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

kubectl makes API calls to the Kubernetes API server in the background, so I guess you could use any of the official or community-mantained client libraries to achieve what you describe. You can find the list of libraries [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/using-api/client-libraries/).

The apply command can generate a a bunch of different API calls depending on the object it is applied onto, if it is a new object or if it exists already, etc. I think this is the reason you don't find it available on client libraries

Try running kubectl with any of the commands you would like to get into the automation script. For example

```
kubectl get pods -v=10
```

You'll see the underlying API calls that are generated

```
    GET https://172.17.0.45:8443/api/v1/namespaces/default/pods?limit=500 200 OK in 9 milliseconds
    Response Headers:
        Content-Type: application/json
        Content-Length: 3631
        Date: Fri, 20 Sep 2019 20:21:48GMT 
    ...
```

Maybe a simpler option would be to simply automate via a Powershell script that calls the kubectl native client

Answer (score 1):

Azure Kubernetes Service supports deploying Kubernetes applications using Helm charts. Using [Helm](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/kubernetes-helm) for automated deployments is a better option.